# PHP Static code Analysis - Finding Class Dependancies

Tags: php, refactoring, static, continuous-integration, code-analysis

I am about to start a large refactoring job on a big PHP project.

I have successfully used pdepend to generate dependancy reports on the packages outlined in the PHPDoc blocks at the start of every file.

The information is really usefull, it outlines dependancies between packages (which packages are used by which, cyclic dependancies etc).

However I'd like to go one step further and get this data on individual classes. Ideally it would be a tool that compiled a report similar to pdepend however I'd settle for a command line tool that takes the name of a class and the path of a project and returns a list of files the class is used by.

Thanks for your help!

Ben

Comment: *(related)* [PHP QA Tools](http://phpqatools.org/)

Comment: Thanks for link Gordon - the tools in here do help with the problem I'm facing. In particular the dead code checker. 
Still holding out for a class dependancy tracking tool though :)

Answer (score 2):

I recently stumbled across this [class graph generation script](http://westhoffswelt.de/blog/class_dependency_graph_generation.html) ([SVN repo here](http://westhoffswelt.de/blog/class_dependency_graph_generation_update.html)). I haven't had time to play with it yet.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work right, I think some of the regex is off because when running it against wordpress it includes comments as classes.